# Fixed scrollbar position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, in my html file I have a `div` that has huge width and height. Vertically it is shown full, so you need to scroll down the whole page. But horizontally only half is shown, so on the bottom of this `div` we have a scrollbar that allows to ride over this `div` without scrolling the whole page left or right.

And the problem is that the scrollbar itself is just placed at the bottom of the `div`, but I want it to be fixed to the bottom of the screen, so I could scroll this `div` to the left and to the right without going down at first.

Is there any possibility to do this, using CSS, jQuery or whatever?

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: is my code really needed to explain how to make scrollbar with fixed position?

Answer (score 0):

What i understand your question 
If you don't need Vertical scroll then simple write and your horizontal scroll display only when your page page content wider than page...

**overflow-y: hidden;**

**overflow-x: auto;**

Answer (score 0):

You can User overflow rule in css.

Vertical Scrolling : `overflow-y : hidden`

Horizontal Scrolling : `overflow-x : hidden`